How can I programmatically set the language in Jetpack Compose without AppCompatDelegate?
I'm trying to implement language selection functionality in my Jetpack Compose app. However, I encountered a roadblock when attempting to use AppCompactDelegate to achieve this. It seems that AppCompactDelegate is not available in Jetpack Compose.
Here's the code snippet I tried:
fun languageUpdate(context: Context, language: String){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
            context.getSystemService(LocaleManager::class.java)
                .applicationLocales = LocaleList.forLanguageTags(language)
        } else {
            AppCompactDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(language))
        }
    }

Since AppCompactDelegate isn't an option in Jetpack Compose, I'm seeking alternative solutions to programmatically set the language in my app. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

just extend your activity with AppCompatActivity and use AppCompatDelegate it's the best way to change language, else use updateConfiguration

Compose works with Component activity, Activity and also AppCompatActivity

You can combine what Megh Lath proposed, but with a combination of using context.createConfigurationContext for android 12 and above, because resources.updateConfiguration was deprecated for android 12 and on.
val context = LocalContext.current
val resources = context.resources
val configuration = resources.configuration

val newContext = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration.apply {
    setLocale(newLocale)
})
LocalContext.current = newContext

If you want to call AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(), you can do it in SideEffect block or LaunchedEffect in Jetpack Compose UI, depending on your needs:
SideEffect {   
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales()
}


In my question please have a look. I have the solution for 12 and above but below that i'm using resources.updateConfiguration i need solution for that.

I updated the answer, I hope that it will help you, if not feel free to reach out with more context.

You can directly update the application's configuration using Resources.updateConfiguration() method.
Here's how you can implement it:

fun updateLanguage(context: Context, language: String) {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    val configuration = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
    configuration.setLocale(locale)

    context.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, context.resources.displayMetrics)
}


And call it through onCreate() or if you want to call it from composable function then cast context as Activity:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    updateLanguage(this, "es")
}

or,
@Composable
fun Sample() {
    val context = LocalContext.current as Activity
    updateLanguage(this, "es")
}


yes i tried that hwat the problem is that updateConfiguration is deprectaed

Then you should have mentioned that tried thing in your question at the first place so that no one include that answer
